# Infrastructure and accommodation in eastern Zambia

Tags: accommodation, bicycles, zambia

I want to travel by bike, coming from Malawi (crossing the border in Mchinji) and continuing to Lusaka, following the road close to the border with Mozambique.

What can I expect on the road, are there many villages with guesthouses and places where I can buy food on the road? It's difficult to figure this out just from Google Maps and [Wikitravel](https://wikitravel.org/en/Eastern_Zambia) just claims it's the least developed province.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not terribly well qualified to answer this question, but there's probably not all that many other Travel.SErs who have traveled on the road in question, even a good ten years ago...

So.  From Mchinji in Malawi across the border to [Chipata](https://wikitravel.org/en/Chipata), the largest town in eastern Zambia, is only about 30 km and easily covered in a day.  Chipata has a large [Shoprite](https://www.shoprite.co.zm/store-locator.html) supermarket for stocking up and a smattering of guesthouses and restaurants etc; [Mama Rula's](https://www.mamarulas.com/) is apparently still there and you could probably do worse than stay there, although it's a few clicks in the wrong direction towards Mfuwe.

[image]
*Which of these will be your future home away from home?* (pic by me)

From Chipata to Lusaka you're on the [Great East Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_East_Road), which is the main highway connecting Lusaka to all points east.  There is thus a steady stream of trucks, buses etc and the infrastructure to cater for them.  That said, this is the African bush and there are *no* towns of size along the way, so you're not going to find anything approaching Western standards, but if you're OK with *[nshima](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Zambia#Eat)* and grotty rooms with a fan if you're lucky, you'll survive.  [Bridge Camp](https://tracks4africa.co.za/listings/item/w147297/bridge-camp-luangwa/), around the halfway mark near an otherside pretty desolate stretch, is apparently still there as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Kuba Glad to hear this was useful, but please do try to get some up-to-date info as well -- I was there >10 years ago, in the comfort of an air-conditioned car, and didn't go all the way to Lusaka.